# How to solve this integration question?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been trying to solve this question with the simple methods I knew but couldn't come to the solution. I would appreciate a bit of hint to solve this integral problem?

$\;\displaystyle\int\frac {e^x}x\,dx$

> Edit : Can't it be solved even if certain upper and lower limits are involved?

Comment: $\int\dfrac{e^x}{x}dx=\int\dfrac{1}{x}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{n!}dx=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n!}dx=\int\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n!}\right)dx=\ln x+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{n!n}+C$

Answer (score 4):

The anti-derivative of this is known as the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) and has no closed forms.